# Cannot compress files after upgrading to Ubuntu16.04

Tags: 16.04, compression

I just found that I cannot compress files using the default built-in compression function of Ubuntu. It just stop at the middle. It used to work well. Decompression is ok with no problem.

I just upgraded to 16.04 last week. Don't know if that's the problem. Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Just tried to find out the problem. It may be due to file size. I can compress small files. But fail when compressing even one single file of several hundred MBs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you move your `/tmp` and `/var` to `tmpfs (ramdisk)` ? I had this same problem compressing large files on my system, while small files compressed very quickly. The issue was because I moved `/tmp`, `/var` to `tmpfs`, and my system was simply running out of memory when compressing.

Can you please edit your question by pasting the output of `cat /etc/fstab`
.